# Добавление классов при нахождении в ссылках определенных фраз

Tags: javascript

Есть задача из разных ссылок сделать форматирование чтоб можно было с помощью css сделать так чтоб они были по порядку пример

движок формирует такого вида блок

```
<ul>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-kuzov-mk1.6/"></a>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-tuning-mk1.10/"></a>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-zvik-mk1.4/"></a>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-electronika-mk1.18/"></a>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-dvizhok-mk1.25/"></a>
<a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-sets-mk1.1/"></a>
</ul>
```

и на каждой странице динамически меняется их положение 
но слова kuzov , dvizhok и тд всегда фигурируют возможно ли как прогонять этот список постоянно и по фразам в ссылке присваивать класс например:

```
<ul>
<a class="kuzov" href="threads/audi-tt-kuzov-mk1.6/"></a>
<a class="tuning" href="threads/audi-tt-tuning-mk1.10/"></a>
<a class="zvik" href="threads/audi-tt-zvik-mk1.4/"></a>
<a class="electrika" href="threads/audi-tt-electronika-mk1.18/"></a>
<a class="dvizhok" href="threads/audi-tt-dvizhok-mk1.25/"></a>
<a class="sets" href="threads/audi-tt-sets-mk1.1/"></a>
</ul>
```

и так далее

Я не совсем разбираюсь в javascript

Пытался по образцу но не получается именно фразу найти

```
window.onload = function() {
const template = ( link, title ) => `<li class="link-list-item"><a href="${ link }">${ title }</a></li>`;

let messages = document.body.querySelectorAll( '.Tooltip' );

let html = Array.from( messages ).reduce( (result, element) => {
  let text = element.innerText;
  let titles = text.match( /dvizhok/g );


  if( titles ){
    let link = element.querySelector('.Tooltip').href;

    return result += template( link, titles[1] ) + '\n';
  }

  return result;
}, "" );


let linkList = document.body.querySelector('.link-list');
linkList.innerHTML = html;}
```

но это скорей всего не в ту степь потому что нужно оставлять на месте просто добавлять класс , и еще не понимаю как с кешированием это все сделать чтоб человек не видел что это происходит пока страница грузится

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#target a')).forEach(a => {
  if(a.href.includes('threads/')){
    a.classList.add(a.href.match(/[a-z]+-[a-z]+-([a-z]+)/i)[1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id='target'>
  <li>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-kuzov-mk1.6/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-tuning-mk1.10/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-zvik-mk1.4/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-electronika-mk1.18/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-dvizhok-mk1.25/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/audi-tt-sets-mk1.1/"></a>
    <a class="Tooltip" href="threads/daewooi-nexia-kuzov.50/"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: тут просто все будет меняться в ссылках кроме этих фраз нужно именно при нахождении фразы в ссылке чтоб добавлял тот  класс который нужно добавить при нахождении такой то фразы

Comment: Ничего не понял. Напишите понятнее. Вроде похоже на Ваш пример работы.

Comment: Просто здесь как понимаю обработка цепляется за audi-tt- а в форуме там будут меняться сами фразы daewooi-nexia-kuzov.50/ и тд

Comment: @titan_ime, вот как... Привели бы хоть один пример в шапке. ОК, сейчас поправим.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать в CSS селекторы по аттрибутам вместо классов.

```css
a[href*=engine] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="/link-to-engine-of-audi">Engine Link</a>
```

---

Или использовать их же, для поиска нужных ссылок:

```js
var keywords = ['dvizhok', 'kuzov', 'tuning', 'zvik', 'electrika'];
keywords.forEach(word => {
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href*='+word+']')
    .forEach(el => el.classList.add(word));
})
```

```css
.kuzov{color: red;}
.tuning{color: green;}
.zvik{color: yellow;}
.electrika{color: black;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="threads/audi-tt-kuzov-mk1.6/">1</a>
<li><a href="threads/audi-tt-tuning-mk1.10/">2</a>
<li><a href="threads/toyota-super-zvik-/">3</a>
<li><a href="threads/mers-tt-electrika-mk1.18/">4</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Предлагаете создать N селекторов по аттрибутам? Жестоко Вы :)

Comment: Ну n классов, вы же для чего-то создаёте? Я предлагаю использовать их **вместо** классов

Comment: Аттрибуты тяжелее на порядок, нежели классы.

Comment: Дописал js решение на тех же селекторах

Comment: Думал многое знаю о css но что такие вещи можно творить реально круто , мне подходит потому что у меня максимум будет 10 классов это просто для форума  и css он быстрее от рисуется и не будет заметно что манипуляции какие то производятся со ссылками . Спасибо огромное )